# Fondant cover cake sagging

Tags: fondant

I bought a 6 inch cake with butter cream icing from a store. I remove the fruits and smoothed out the icing. I colored my Wilton fondant with blue gel color and roll it and cover the cake. It started to have tiny cracks immediately. I put it in front of window air-conditioner for several hours and it stabilized. I put it in the box and keep it in fridge. It looks good in the fridge. on the birthday day, only 10 minutes after I remove it from fridge, the cover started sagging and melting to the point that we could not use the cake anymore. While making the fondant cover, I tried to make sure the cover thickness is 1/8 inch. I color the white fondant with gel color, do you think that's the reason? I used a lot of finely powdered sugar while rolling the fondant to remove stickiness. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the experience to be sure, but my guess is that by adding lots of powdered sugar while rolling you dried out the fondant so it was no longer as flexible, hence the cracking. What do you mean by sagging here – was there empty space between the fondant and the cake surface?

Comment: Did the cake compress?  Many types of cake are too light and airy to support heavy decorations.  It’s a difficult balance so it’s strong enough for stacking without being too dry & heavy when eating